# Javascript every() method for class object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have made a grid of boxes is javascript. I want to check if my mouse is on none of them with the every() method. I have a built in hover function for my class but I don't know how to implement the method.

```js
class area {

    constructor(x, y, w, h) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.w = w
        this.h = h
        this.posx = width - (x + w)
        this.posy = height / row_num

    }

    hover(mx, my) {
        if (mx > this.x && mx < this.x + this.w && my > this.y && my < this.y + this.h) {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    
    for (let i = 0; i < hovergrid.length; i++) {
        

        if (hovergrid[i].hover(mouseX, mouseY)) {
  }



    const isValid = hovergrid.every(item => item.hover(mouseX, mouseY) === true)
    console.log({ isValid })
```

```html
<img id="displayedimage" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.style.display = 'none'" src="images/1.png">
```

Here is what i have tried, but it didn't work out properly. Someone can give me some hint? Thanks a lot `

```
   const isValid = hovergrid.every(item => item.hover(mouseX, mouseY) === true)
   console.log({ isValid })
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code

```
hover(mx, my) {
        if (mx > this.x && mx < this.x + this.w && my > this.y && my < this.y + this.h) {
            return true
        }
```

This is returning only **true** but not **false**.
every() function expects boolean return. but in this function in case of false nothing is getting returned.
So, I believe after including that part "every()" should work properly.